# Como faço para um dialog fechar quando a condição for verdadeira?

Tags: java, android, alertdialog

Como posso fazer para que um custom alertDialog feche após o usuário ativar o gps? A caixa do dialog tbm não pode fechar enquanto a condição do gps for falsa, ou seja, enquanto ele estiver desativado o alertDialog tem que permanecer, mas quando ativo o gps a caixa do dialog ainda permanece.

Seguem meu code:

```
LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
final boolean enabled = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (!enabled) {

    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog__custom, null);

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);


    view.findViewById(R.id.btn_claro).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            onStop();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btn_depois).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            AlertSair();
        }
    });
    alert.dismiss();
    alertDialog.setView(view);
    alertDialog.show();

} onResume();
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar o **startActivityForResult**

exemplo:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.btn_claro).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        onStop();
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 1);
    }
});
```

E quando o usuário ativar o GPS vai voltar o resultado:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == 1) {
           switch (requestCode) {
              case 1:

               //aqui fecha o alerta                   

               break;
            }
        }  
}
```

Comment: Você poderia ser um pouco mais claro? Não conseguir aplicar no meu code. continua a mesma coisa. O alerta ainda continua mesmo depois de ativar. Como fazer para fechar o AlertDialog dentro dessa condição? Sou iniciante ainda.. =(

Comment: A parte de cima que falou entendi, mas a de baixo não conseguir aplicar no meu code.

Comment: Outra duvida também é como posso fazer com que sempre fique fazendo a verificação se o gps está ou nao ativado? pq o usuario pode habilitar e desabilitar e o programa não faz outra verificação pra saber. alguma luz? obrigado desde já amigo